# After naming ng-app breaks the code

Tags: angularjs

My app works just fine without any ng-app name , when I name it angular don't work ! I am working with angular version 1.2.6 .
Here is my code sample

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="hiren">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"></head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="center-block">
        <div id="sidebar-left" class="col-lg-2 col-2" >
          <ul class="nav bs-sidenav">
            <li>
              <a href="#/x">Home</a>
              <a href="/">Playlist</a>
              <a href="/">Browse</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" >
        <div class="ng-view"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="dist/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="dist/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="dist/js/controler.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

controler.js

```
var hirenx = angular.module('hiren',[]);

hirenx.config(['$routeProvider' ,
    function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when('/x' ,{
            templateUrl: 'x.html' ,
            controller : 'hireny'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }]);

hirenx.controller('hireny' , function($scope){
    $scope.message = "example" ;
});
```

Here is the sample partial . 
x.html

```
<h2>{{ message }}</h2>
```

Comment: Check if there is any error in the console. Do you see `<h2>{{ message }}</h2>`?

Comment: what is the error your getting?

Comment: Here is the error
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=hiren&p1=Error%3A%2…b%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A2000%2Fdist%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A125)

Comment: Use the un-minified version and it will show you the missing module required. That error is usually when you're missing required module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 1.2 you need to include `ngRoute` in your dependencies:

```
var hirenx = angular.module('hiren',['ngRoute']);
```